# The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed in mvc 5

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-mvc-5

I use to login in gmail throgh my application using same credential as we      used    for gmail login. 
         i am getting The remote server returned an error:

> (405) Method Not Allowed,

on

```
 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Below is my Code sample:

```
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var captcha = model.catchpa;
        var username = model.Email;
        var user = "UserName";
        var password = model.Password;
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("username={0}&user={1}&password={2}&captcha={3}", username, user, password, captcha));
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
        request.Accept = "*";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", " gzip, deflate, br");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.5");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "x-apm-brtm-bt-p=Chrome; x-apm-brtm-bt-pv=55; x-apm-brtm-bt-url=%2F; WMRUMC=%7B%7D; CaptchaCookie=6cd0895847f3412e842dff4d932543e6; x-apm-brtm-response-bt=bs%3D-1%2Cbt%3D-1%2Cbtc%3D-1%2CCorBrowsGUID%3D4521608D0AF27A07195F9576C4193CD6%2Curl%3D%2Fservices%2Fcaptcha; x-apm-brtm-response-bt-id=_oxn3avih0");
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Host = "services.gst.gov.in";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0";
        request.Referer = "https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login";

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Here i explai what actually i want:

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
request.Method = "POST";
```

You are using HTTP POST to obtain your data. The server does not accept your post request, either because POST is not allowed at all or your request is incomplete.

Use a HTTP sniffing tool like *Fiddler* and do your request manually in a web browser. There you can see how to correctly access the page.

Comment: do you mean to say that, there should be 2 pages .one page to post httpwebrequest and another page to GET same request.

Comment: @KumarHarsh That depends entirely on the site you are accessing. It is absolutely possible (and very common) that one page supports multiple request methods. You just have to get the right one in your client.

Comment: Thanks for reply.in fact there should be two method,POST and GET.I have to upload file in remote server using" http WebDAV".Do you have any complete example ?Can you help ?